# Doctrine - how to keep ManyToOne synchronized?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping, associations

After reading the Doctrine reference and the Symfony tutorial on it, I started integrating it in a project. I'm experiencing a problem I thought doctrine could solve:

I want to have `Libraries` with many `Collections`, which I assume to be a 'ManytoOne' relationship as the Collection will keep the foreign key.

Some snippets:

In Library:

```
/**
*
* @var ArrayCollection
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Collection", mappedBy="library")
*/
private $collections;
```

In collection:

```
 /**
 * @var Library
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Library", inversedBy="collections")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="library_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $library;
```

Since most of this annotations are default and could be left out it's a pretty basic setup.

A sample controller code:

```
    $library = new Library();
    $library->setName("Holiday");
    $library->setDescription("Our holiday photos");

    $collection = new Collection();
    $collection->setName("Spain 2011");
    $collection->setDescription("Peniscola");

    $library->addCollection($collection);

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($collection);
    $em->persist($library);        
    $em->flush();
```

The code above won't set the `library_id` column in the `Collection` table, which I assume is because `Library` is not the owner.

```
    $library = new Library();
    $library->setName("Holiday");
    $library->setDescription("Our holiday photos");

    $collection = new Collection();
    $collection->setName("Spain 2011");
    $collection->setDescription("Peniscola");

    $collection->setLibrary($library); <--- DIFFERENCE HERE

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($collection);
    $em->persist($library);
    $em->flush();
```

Works. But I want to be able to use the library add and remove methods.

Is it common to alter these add and remove methods to call the `setLibrary` method?

```
public function addCollection(\MediaBox\AppBundle\Entity\Collection $collections)
{
    $this->collections[] = $collections;
    $collections->setLibrary($this);
    return $this;
}
```

and

```
public function removeCollection(\MediaBox\AppBundle\Entity\Collection $collections)
{
    $this->collections->removeElement($collections);
    $collections->setLibrary(null);
}
```

I don't think that's very nice.

Is it best practice in doctrine or ORM in general?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is the way to go.

For the case someone needs it:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods

Explains this problem.